# Authentication using face in android

Tags: android

How to create app to unlock application and need to authenticate only from already stored face scanned by device for screen lock.

I want to unlock app using that scanned face like finger authentication.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887994/how-can-i-use-androids-face-unlock-within-my-own-private-application

Comment: not matching my requirement

Comment: In Finger authentication  it fetch finger print already stored in device but this case not working for face.

Comment: There's no official way of doing this _just yet_ according to https://source.android.com/security/biometric